# Python URL Regex

Tags: python, regex

I've a url and a regex. I want to check whether the url matches the regex or not.

I'm checking it on Amazon product urls. Amazon Product URLs have `dp` in their urls. For eg:-

```
https://www.amazon.in/product-slug/dp/B07655JJYT
https://www.amazon.in/product-slug/some/path/dp/B00W9E8O80/ref?query_param=value
https://www.amazon.in/dp/B00W9E8O80/
```

I want to match all the above-given type of URLs.

Below is my code:-

```
import re

url = 'https://www.amazon.in/Perfect-Pricee-Cupcake-Steel-Muffin/dp/B07655JJYT'
pattern = "^*://www.amazon.in/*/dp/*$"

if re.search(pattern, url):
    print(1)
```

I'm not well versed with regexes. Not sure why it throws an error.

Comment: The regex for "any sequence of any length" is not `*`, but `.*`

Comment: @Allan - It works. Could you also please publish this as an answer explaining what `.*(?<=/)` does?

Comment: @PythonEnthusiast: I want to help you more but your question is a duplicate so I can't post anymore answer. you can have a look at: https://regex101.com/r/Pfl3Uc/2/
for demo and explanations.

Comment: `^.*://www\.amazon\.in/.*(?<=/)dp/.*$` is better as `\.` will take the dot litteraly